Laravel 5 Laravel-Pusher
Alguien me puede ayudar, tengo un pagina desarrollada con laravel para el backend que por cierto ya esta subida a producción, el problema es que estoy tratando de instalar pusher pero me da varios errores y no se si hay forma de solucionarlos, estos son los errores que me da a ejecutar el comando: root@riocargomaster:/var/www/deliverylast# composer require pusher/pusher-php-server Using version ^7.2 for pusher/pusher-php-server ./composer.json has been updated Running composer update pusher/pusher-php-server Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1 - fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.9.2 and an update of this package was not requested. - fzaninotto/faker v1.9.2 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement. Problem 2 - phpunit/phpunit is locked to version 5.7.27 and an update of this package was not requested. - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.27 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement. Problem 3 - dompdf/dompdf v0.8.6 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement. - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.2 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.6]. - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf is locked to version v0.8.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require pusher/pusher-php-server:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require pusher/pusher-php-server:^2.1" if you know which you need.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
Estas son mis versiones de laravel y php: "php": ">=5.6.4", "laravel/framework": "5.4.*"

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

No soy un experto en laravel pero por lo que veo tienes un problema de dependencia de paquetes.
El problema los tienes en la version que tienes de laravel y php ya que no son compatibles.
En tu archivo composer.json debes eliminar los paquetes que te generan conflicto
composer.json

#Ejemplo
{
    "require": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.7",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^1.0"
    }

   //quedaria asi:
    "require": {
        "otro/paquete": "^1.7",
    }

}

Elimina las dependencias que te causan conflicto dentro del archivo "require".
ejecuta en la terminal dentro de la ruta de tu proyecto:
composer update

reinstala los paquetes que te generaban conflicto:
composer require fakerphp/faker

de esta forma podras solucionar los detalles en tus paquetes.

eso no se resuelve asi ... el problema tiene un contexto y es lo siguiente ... ya esta desarrollado y corre en php 5.6, cualquier paquete que instale debe hacer una investigacion previsa e instalar la ultima version especifica con soporte para php 5.6 de lo contrario si lo hace a ciegas ... seguira teniendo el mismo problema...

jaja el problema del contexto tienes razon gg, lo que si me saco duda el OP es que menciona que tiene php 5.6 pero en los mensajes de errores tiene instalado php 8.3.4 :v .

si es correcto por eso he editado mi respuesta para que avarque en el tal caso que tenga la version 8.3.4 corriedo en el CLI... ya que es lo mismo  ...

He trabajado un poco con laravel los últimos años y otros muchos con composer ... y puedo decirte que tienes dos problemas no uno:

PHP 5.6.* está obsoleto y todos los paquetes que vayas a ejecutar sobre esa versión serán difícil de instalar o darán algún problema raro de compatibilidad etc ...

El Avance que tienes en el proyecto coacciona negativamente la escalabilidad del proyecto.


Bueno ahora veamos posibles soluciones:
Primero, actualiza composer.json para reemplazar y actualizar las dependencias. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo puede quedar tu archivo composer.json:
{
    "name": "your/project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "3.4.1"
    }
}

nota: recuerda colocar todas la librerias que usas... esto es solo un ejemplo.
Luego, elimina composer.lock y la carpeta vendor para asegurarte de que todas las dependencias se reinstalen correctamente.
Después, ejecuta el comando de instalación de Composer:
composer install
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server

Con esto ya deberia de funcionar correctamente si tienes php 5.6 instalado ... en caso de no tenerlo instalado tendrias que instalarlo manualmente, aqui hay una guia: Es posible lograr la configuración de Laragon implementando Virtual Host y la ejecución de múltiples versiones de php al mismo tiempo?
Nota: solo recomiendo usar la versión PHP obsoleta cuando ya hay un proyecto desarrollado... teniendo en cuenta que si o si necesitas ejecutarlo  para luego actualizarlo a una versión más reciente.
